# Implementing A Home button in SWReavealViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using an SWRevealViewController and one of the Contents of the cell is called "Home". The rest of the contents go to another VieController, but the Home button should take the App to the First ViewController. I tried

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:viewC animated:YES];
```

(viewC is the First ViewController) I also tried

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

neither works. Can someone with experience in SWRevealViewController, help?
 The First View Controller is the sw_front for the RevealViewController and The Table View in which the cell ("HOME") exists is at the sw_rear.
First ViewController is the first page that appears when the app is opened

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
_rowSelected=(int)indexPath.row;
if (_rowSelected==0) {
    ViewController *viewC;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toHome" sender:self];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewC animated:YES];
}
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"sideBarSegue" sender:self];
}
```

I have tried all 3 methods here separately and none has worked

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toHome" sender:self];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewC animated:YES];
```

this part is an "else" case that redirects to another ViewController that works fine

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"sideBarSegue" sender:self];
```

Comment: What is the First view controller? Is it the first front view controller when you start the app? Is it dynamic everytime? Provide more details..  Also, where is this "cell", which view controller? You need to provide screenshots perhaps.

Comment: Ok, the First View Controller is the sw_front for the RevealViewController and The Table View in which the cell ("HOME") exists is at the sw_rear. I wish i can post the screenshot but i Can't

Comment: Ok, Can you please paste your code from the rear view controller for the method: tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: please see my answer below and let me know if it fits your need. Please accept the answer if it does. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have implemented is probably not the right approach to segue once you select the cell in the rear view controller. Instead, you should set the front view controller in the reveal controller again to achieve this. This how I would do it (and I have not used Segues):

`menuItems` is the data source for your table view
`previousItem` is just a string I use to check what is the last selection made by the user. If the last selection is same as the new one, I just reset the position.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *item = [[menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] uppercaseString];
    UINavigationController *newController;
    if (![item isEqualToString:previousItem])
    {
        if ([item isEqualToString:@"HOME"])
            newController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewNavigationController"];

        ....... //conditions here for other cells.

        previousItem = item;

        [self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:newController];
        [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition:FrontViewPositionLeft animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition:FrontViewPositionLeft animated:YES];
    }
}
```

This is assuming your have a home view controller identifier defined in your storyboard and is embedded in a navigation controller. Or you can instantiate it by doing alloc init as well.

Let me know if you have any questions.

hope this helps.

Comment: I have a question. Where do we set an identifier for a ViewController? Is it in Storyboard ID?

Comment: Yes. You should do it there. Also set it for the Navigation controller that you embedded your view in. Not the actual view controller.

Comment: Hey that worked. Thank you so much. not just for the answer , but also better explaining the working

Comment: No problem at all :) Glad I could help! Thanks for the upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

Following answer is helpful for you.

```
      1.If you have given triggered segue connection in storyboard, remove triggered segue connection.
      2.Then give push segue connection to Home Button to your required view controller(I mean you want to back first view controller).
      3.Click Home Button Segue and give Identifier name as "goToYourViewController" or whatever you want just give there.Also segue should be "push".
```

Comment: If you have any queries please ask me

Comment: I did not implement the Table View using prototype cells. I created a cell outside in xib. I can't follow the procedure you suggested here, can I?

Comment: It is not a problem.Even if you create the custom cell,you have to write the same thing.Most of the time i used custom cell only and in didSelectRowAtIndexPath you have to write segue action for each cell.

Comment: Why did you write [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES] and
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewC animated:YES] these two lines in your method?

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Comment: not yet, no..i used [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES] and [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewC animated:YES]  as diffrent attempts for the same thing. didnt use them together\

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. your suggestion almost worked. but when the original VC appears, the buttons inside it, disappears

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85290/discussion-between-user3182143-and-sidharth-j-dev).